# Magento REST API Problems

Tags: php, magento, rest, oauth

I am trying to create a product with the REST API of Magento, so i am using the example PHP code of the Magento REST API docs.
When the process finishes i always get an error message:

```
[message:protected] => Invalid auth/bad request (got a 404, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)
```

The product will be successfully created in Magento's backend BUT it will not be listed in the frontend shop until you manually open and save the product (without changing any values).

Any ideas?
Thanks!

**Edit:** Updating an existing product works without errors (but will also not show products wich are not saved manually).